# Echo server with CompletableFuture

Tags: java, asynchronous, networking, socket, java-8

I recently wrote a simple echo server in Java 7 using the NIO APIs so it was asynchronous and non-blocking. Then I decided, as a learning experience, to redo it with Java 8 hoping to use a more functional style and not have nested callbacks. I'm struggling to understand how to use the new `CompletableFuture` class with the `Future`s returned by `AsynchronousSocketChannel`.

This code currently works but is slower than the Java 7 version. If anyone can point out ways to improve it (or maybe that I'm going about it completely wrong) it would be appreciated. The main problem, to me at least, is that I now have to call `get()` on three `Future`s, whereas before I didn't have any blocking operations.

```
try (final AsynchronousServerSocketChannel listener = 
    AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open()) {

        listener.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, true);
        listener.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8080));

        while (true) {      

            AsynchronousSocketChannel connection = listener.accept().get();
            CompletableFuture<AsynchronousSocketChannel> connectionPromise = 
                CompletableFuture.completedFuture(connection);

            CompletableFuture<ByteBuffer> readerPromise = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024);
                try {
                    connection.read(buffer).get();
                    return (ByteBuffer) buffer.flip();
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    connectionPromise.completeExceptionally(e);
                } 
                return null;
            });

            readerPromise.thenAcceptAsync((buffer) -> {
                if (buffer != null) {
                    try {
                        connection.write(buffer).get();
                        connection.close();
                    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | IOException e) {
readerPromise.completeExceptionally(e);
                    } 
                }
            });
        }

    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: " is slower than the Java 7 version.": Can we see the other version? Maybe we could spot the difference.

Comment: Sure, Java 7 version - https://gist.github.com/opiethehokie/9435565. BTW this wasn't a serious performance test, just an observation that it was noticeably slower when I had a client program send a few thousand requests.

Comment: That's ok. I just want to see if there are other differences, like as you said `listener.accept().get()` was synchronous in the Java 8 version, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What to do with checked Exceptions thrown within a `CompletableFuture`?

Let's look what does `CompletableFuture` do with the unchecked exceptions.
As *@palacsint* noted:

> In all other cases, if a stage's computation terminates abruptly with
>   an (unchecked) exception or error, then all dependent stages requiring
>   its completion complete exceptionally as well, with a
>   CompletionException holding the exception as its cause.

That is to say: If `completableFuture.get()` would throw, say, an `ExecutionException:NullPointerException`; then so would `future.thenApply(funcOne).get()` and `future.thenApply(funcOne).thenApply(funcTwo).get()` and so on. This is done by at each stage a layer of `CompletionException` is peeled and wrapped in another. `.get()` peels it and wraps it in an `ExecutionException` so that the contents of the `ExecutionException` is not drowned in layers and layers of `CompletionException`s.

So what will happen if you wrap a checked exception in a `CompletionException`. It will percolate through the chain and you would get a `ExecutionException:IOException`, as if you could throw a checked exception from a `Supplier<T>`. Which you can handle differently than if you just wrapped in a `RuntimeException`. This is what you try to do when you do `connectionPromise.completeExceptionally(e);` as far as I can understand. And it is what would happen if someone else called `completeExceptionally` on the enclosing `CompletableFuture`. I am proposing this; because you might want to prefer unrecoverable `RuntimeException`s to be program errors **as much as prudent**(, and no more). If I am ignoring fifty `RuntimeException`s because some clients have sketchy wireless connection, then I might ignore some other `RuntimeException` that is indicative of a grave programming error. To be fair this may be considered as depending on undocumented behavior. If you are troubled by this, you can define you on you own unchecked checked exception wrapper.

Finally on this point; looking at the API `CompletableFuture`s are clearly meant to be chained.

### Accepting Connections Synchronously

You need not really do this. You can either start the `CompletableFuture` chain with a call to `supplyAsync` giving it a suitable `Executor` such as a fixed thread pool or cached poll or a custom `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Or similarly you accept connections in a callback using `AsynchronousChannelGroup`. Since I do not know about NIO2 I am copying that part from [some online source](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-nio2-1/index.html).

```
public static void serverLoop() throws IOException {
    // These can be injected and thus configured from without the application
    ExecutorService connectPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    Executor readPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    Executor writePool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    AsynchronousChannelGroup group = AsynchronousChannelGroup.withThreadPool(connectPool);

    try (AsynchronousServerSocketChannel listener = 
             AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open(group)) {
        listener.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, true);
        listener.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8080));

        while (true) {
            listener.accept(null, handlerFrom(
                (AsynchronousSocketChannel connection, Object attachment) -> {
                    assert attachment == null;
                    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> { 
                        try {
                            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024);
                            connection.read(buffer).get();
                            return (ByteBuffer) buffer.flip();
                        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                            throw new CompletionException(ex);
                        }}, readPool)
                    .thenAcceptAsync((buffer) -> {
                        try {
                            if (buffer == null) return;
                            connection.write(buffer).get();
                        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                            throw new CompletionException(ex);
                        }
                    }, writePool)
                    .exceptionally(ex -> {
                        handleException(ex); 
                        return null;
                    });
                }));
        }
    }        
}

private static <V, A> CompletionHandler<V, A> handlerFrom(BiConsumer<V, A> completed) {
    return handlerFrom(completed, (Throwable exc, A attachment) -> {
                    assert attachment == null;
                    handleException(exc);
                });
}

private static <V, A> CompletionHandler<V, A> handlerFrom(
        BiConsumer<V, A> completed, 
        BiConsumer<Throwable, A> failed) {
    return new CompletionHandler<V, A>() {
        @Override
        public void completed(V result, A attachment) {
            completed.accept(result, attachment);
        }

        @Override
        public void failed(Throwable exc, A attachment) {
            failed.accept(exc, attachment);
        }
    };
}
```

### Escaping from Callback Hell

This is more a comment than a review item. As far as I looked, there is not a fluent interface yet for general `Future`s. You could roll out your own, but you would have to implement dozens of methods yourself. Because of the peculiarities of Java's type system, one cannot have real monads, traits, extension methods etc facilities other languages provide for library developers that help with this burden.

### EDIT

I realized that it is possible to do this:

> hoping to use a more functional style and not have nested callbacks.

*But I do not claim for one moment this is better than the usual callback hell.*

```
CompletableFuture.completedFuture(
    (TriConsumer<CompletionHandler<Integer, ByteBuffer>, ByteBuffer, AsynchronousSocketChannel>)
    (self, bbAttachment, scAttachment) -> {
        if (bbAttachment.hasRemaining()) {
            scAttachment.write(bbAttachment, bbAttachment, self);
        } else {
            bbAttachment.clear();
        }
    })
    .thenApply((consumer) -> (
        (TriConsumer<Integer, ByteBuffer, AsynchronousSocketChannel>)
        (result, buffer, scAttachment) -> {
        if (result == -1) {
            try {
                scAttachment.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        scAttachment.write((ByteBuffer) buffer.flip(), buffer, handlerFrom(
            (Integer result2, ByteBuffer bbAttachment, CompletionHandler<Integer, ByteBuffer> self) -> {
                consumer.accept(self, bbAttachment, scAttachment);
            }));
    }))
    .thenApply((consumer) -> (Consumer<AsynchronousSocketChannel>) connection -> {   
        final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024);
        connection.read(buffer, connection, handlerFrom(
                (Integer result, final AsynchronousSocketChannel scAttachment) -> {
                consumer.accept(result, buffer, scAttachment);
            }));
    })
    .thenAccept((consumer)->
        listener.accept(null, handlerFrom(
            (AsynchronousSocketChannel connection, Void v, CompletionHandler<AsynchronousSocketChannel, Void> self) -> {
                listener.accept(null, self); // get ready for next connection
                consumer.accept(connection);
            })));
```

Where:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface TriConsumer<T1, T2, T3> {
    void accept(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3);
}

private static <V, A> CompletionHandler<V, A> handlerFrom(TriConsumer<V, A, CompletionHandler<V, A>> completed) {
    return handlerFrom(completed, (Throwable exc, A attachment) -> {
                    assert attachment == null;
                    handleException(exc);
                });
}

private static <V, A> CompletionHandler<V, A> handlerFrom(
        TriConsumer<V, A, CompletionHandler<V, A>> completed, 
        BiConsumer<Throwable, A> failed) {
    return new CompletionHandler<V, A>(){
        @Override
        public void completed(V result, A attachment) {
            completed.accept(result, attachment, this);
        }

        @Override
        public void failed(Throwable exc, A attachment) {
            failed.accept(exc, attachment);
        }
    };
}
```

### Remarks

- Since nio2 methods are already async, we stick with the sync methods of `CompletableFuture`.
- Although the callbacks are not nested anymore they are upside down.

Comment: I like the original better as it's easier to follow, but thanks for proving it's possible with the edit. Also good point about the chaining. I really missed out on the chance to do that in the original, not sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score 3):

1. As far as I see `supplyAsync` and `thenAcceptAsync` uses `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` which does not use more than three threads on my machine (and it depends on the number of available processors). It could be a bottleneck if you have more than three clients at the same time. Both methods can have an `Executor` argument which would be used instead of `commonPool()`.
2. The code calls `completeExceptionally` in the `catch` block here:

   > ```
   > readerPromise.thenAcceptAsync((buffer) -> {
   >     if (buffer != null) {
   >         try {
   >             connection.write(buffer).get();
   >             connection.close();
   >         } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | IOException e {
   >             readerPromise.completeExceptionally(e);
   >         } 
   >     }
   > });
   > ```

   It seems to me that it does not have any effect. [Javadoc of `completeExceptionally`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#completeExceptionally-java.lang.Throwable-) says the following:

   > If not already completed, causes invocations of `get()` and related methods to throw the given exception.

   The lambda passed to `thenAcceptAsync` is called when the `CompleteFuture` (`readerPromise` in this case) is already completed so it doesn't change anything. Consider the following PoC:

   ```
   @Test
   public void test3() throws Exception {
       final CompletableFuture<String> reader = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
           return "data";
       });
       reader.thenAcceptAsync(x -> {
           System.out.println("reader.thenAcceptAsync: " + x);
           boolean transitionToCompleted = reader.completeExceptionally(new RuntimeException(
                   "overridden Future result"));
           System.out.println(transitionToCompleted); // prints "false"
       });

       Uninterruptibles.sleepUninterruptibly(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       System.out.println("reader result: " + reader.get()); // prints "data"
   }
   ```

   (Note that there is an [`obtrudeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#obtrudeException-java.lang.Throwable-) method but I guess you don't need that either.)
3. The same is true for `connectionPromise.completeExceptionally(e)`, furthermore, `connectionPromise` seems completely unused in the code above. I'd remove it.
4. [`thenAcceptAsync` will run only when the the previous stage completes normally](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#thenAcceptAsync-java.util.function.Consumer-java.util.concurrent.Executor-). The following also could be useful:

   > In all other cases, if a stage's computation terminates abruptly with an (unchecked) exception or error, then all dependent stages requiring its completion complete exceptionally as well, with a CompletionException holding the exception as its cause.

   Source: [CompletionStage javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html)

   According to that you might be able to change the reader lambda to the following:

   ```
   final CompletableFuture<ByteBuffer> readerPromise = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
       try {
           final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024);
           connection.read(buffer).get();
           buffer.flip();
           return buffer;
       } catch (final Exception e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }
   });
   ```

   It never returns null, so you can remove the null check from writer lambda:

   ```
   final CompletableFuture<Void> writerPromise = readerPromise.thenAcceptAsync((buffer) -> {
       try {
           connection.write(buffer).get();
           connection.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }
   });
   ```

   Finally, if there's an exception, you could log that with the following:

   ```
   writerPromise.exceptionally(x -> {
       x.printStackTrace(); // TODO: use logging instead
       return null;
   });
   ```

   (I'm not familiar with these APIs but this looks right for me.)
5. Note that I've removed the ugly casting with changing

   > ```
   > return (ByteBuffer) buffer.flip();
   > ```

   to

   ```
   buffer.flip();
   return buffer;
   ```
6. Calling `Future.get()` in the lambdas does not seem to asynchronous for me too (althought they're run by another threads) but I've not idea how should it be handled. The two APIs does not seem compatible. (I guess you could get better answers on Stack Overflow with a more specific question.)